# Drawing a cylinder using quadratic form

Tags: pgfplots

So I've been looking for a way to draw a cylinder and I can't seem to find a way to do. How can I get coordinates out of the following implicit function so I can draw it using pgfplots? or is there a way I can plot it using the matrix form?

```
$$1=q(x,y,z)=(x,y,z) \begin{bmatrix}
2& -1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -1\\
-1 &-1 &2
\end{bmatrix} (x,y,z)^T$$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Regarding *how to get coordinates out of the implicit function*, this is off-topic here (even though some people here might be able to answer it, including myself); maybe try a math forum. Regarding whether *there is a way to plot the implicit function*, the answer is no.

Comment: That is not a cylinder, that is an ellipsoid.  The three axes are given by the eigenvectors, and the lengths of these axes by their corresponding eigenvalues (inverse).

Comment: @JohnKormylo It would be an ellipsoid if all three eigenvalues were `>0`, but here, 0 is an eigenvalue, and the level sets are indeed cylinders, with direction the kernel of the quadratic form *here `vect(1,1,1)`*.

Comment: yeah its a cylinder, I drew it in Wolfram using some old gadget but the resolution is really bad it's unusable. I'm not even sure Im legally allowed to use it.

Comment: @marsupilam - Okay, it's a degenerate ellipsoid.  ;-)  But since it is infinitely long you can't actually draw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrize this kind of infinitely expanding degenerate ellipsoid (this is math !). I did this for you.

The cylinders have to be drawn in two times, to deal with the fake 3d between plots : to have the line be *"inside"* the cylinder.

I'll leave it as an exercice to take one cylinder off.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset%{{{
{
  mySurface/.style = 
  {
    mesh, % there should be better options : look at the PGFplots manual
    opacity=.1, 
  }
}
%}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      %{{{
      width=30cm,
      xticklabels=\empty,
      yticklabels=\empty,
      zticklabels=\empty,
      samples = 2, % for the lines
      samples y = 100, % for the circles
      % limits of the box
      xmin = -12, xmax = 12, 
      ymin = -12, ymax = 12,
      zmin = -12, zmax = 12,
      unit vector ratio = 1 1 1,
      % parametrize the 3d view
      view/az=15,
      view/h=80,
      %length of the cylinder
      domain = -8:8,
      %}}}
    ]
    \def\X{\r*cos(y)-\r*sin(y) + x}
    \def\Y{-\r*cos(y)-\r*sin(y) + x}
    \def\Z{2 * \r*sin(y) + x}
    \def\r{2}
    \addplot3[mySurface,domain y= 90:270] ({\X},{\Y},{\Z});
    \def\r{1}
    \addplot3[mySurface,domain y= 90:270] ({\X},{\Y},{\Z});
    \addplot3[domain=-12:12, samples=2, blue, thick] (x,x,x);
    \addplot3[mySurface,domain y= -90:90] ({\X},{\Y},{\Z}); ;
    \def\r{2}
    \addplot3[mySurface,domain y= -90:90] ({\X},{\Y},{\Z}); ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```